# hapijs render xml like sitemaps, feeds

Tags: xml, hapi.js

I couldn't find any documentation in hapijs for rendering xml output, currently my view is rendered like this:

```
server.route({
  path: "/feed/{tag}",
  method: "GET",
  handler: function(req, resp) {
    var tag = req.params.tag;
    Post.findByTag(tag).sort({date: -1}).exec()
        .then(function(posts){
            resp.view("feed", {posts: posts, updated: posts[0].date}, {layout: false});
        });
}
});
```

And my handlebars template `feed.hbs` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

  <title>{{ site.siteTitle }}</title>
  <link href="{{site.siteBaseUrl}}"/>
  <author>
    <name>Adam Stokes</name>
  </author>
  <updated>{{updated}}</updated>
  <id>{{site.siteBaseUrl}}</id>
  {{#each posts}}
  <entry>
    <title>{{this.title}}</title>
    <link href="{{site.siteBaseUrl}}/{{this.permalink}}"/>
    <id>{{site.siteBaseUrl}}/{{this.permalink}}</id>
    <updated>{{this.date}}</updated>
    <summary>{{md this.md}}</summary>
  </entry>
  {{/each}}

</feed>
```

**The Problem:**

Viewing the output in the browser doesn't render as the normal xml output but what seems to be as text.

Question is how do I make sure that the output has the proper headers for rendering in the proper xml format?

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is. Why does your code not work? Do you get an error? What is that error? What did you see vs what you were expecting?

Comment: @MattHarrison thanks updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML is being rendered correctly by handlebars, it's just your browser is interpreting it as HTML and not XML. You just need to indicate the content-type is XML:

```
server.route({
    path: '/feed/{tag}',
    method: "GET",
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        var tag = req.params.tag;
        Post.findByTag(tag).sort({date: -1}).exec()
        .then(function(posts){

            var response = reply.view('feed', {posts: posts, updated: posts[0].date}, {layout: false});
            response.type('application/xml');
        });
    }
});
```

**Aside:**

I recommend you use the standard argument names `request` and `reply`. Your choice of `resp` looks a lot like it represents a response object, but that's not what it is. It's the [`reply()` interface](http://hapijs.com/api#reply-interface). The reply interface actually returns a [response object](http://hapijs.com/api#response-object) (as shown in my answer) which has methods for setting content type etc.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll update my code to fix those standard arguments as well.